# Когда и в каком контексте употреблять слова "подъезд" и "парадная"?

Tags: стилистика, грамотная-речь

В чём ещё различие в употреблении  слов «подъезд» и «парадная»?
Я нашла только следующее. Слово «подъезд» употребляют чаще москвичи, а «парадная» - петербуржцы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё так и есть. Различия - областные, диалектные. Парадная (парадное) - слово питерское, в других местах устаревает.

В общелитературный язык вошел московский синоним - подъезд.
С этим словом всё понятно, а вот питерское "парадная" восходит к тем временам, когда у каждого городского дома (не лачуг и хижин) было минимум два входа - парадный и черный. Так вот, нумерация подъездов и квартир в Петербурге (и не только) базировалась на счете **парадных**.

Захотелось добавить.
Вопрос о том, как нумеруются квартиры, не праздный. Мне довелось пожить в таком доме, где были два парадных и три черных подъезда. Не в Питере, правда, а в Харькове, но ситуация та же.

Всего в доме было 14 квартир, первая половина номеров - в первом 
**парадном** подъезде, вторая - во втором. Но ходили-то все, включая почтальонов, преимущественно с черного... 
Так вот, мне сейчас, хотя я прекрасно представляю внутреннюю планировку дома, даже непросто сообразить, какие квартиры в какой черный подъезд выходили.
Вот сейчас нарисую.

В первом черном подъезде
на первом этаже была кв. №8,
на втором №10,
на третьем №12.

Во втором (моем) было восемь квартир, по этажам -
На первом - №9 и №2,
на втором №11 и №4,
на третьем №13 и №6,
на четвертом №14 и №7.

В третьем черном
на первом этаже была кв. №1,
на втором №3,
на третьем №5.

Во! Это не шутка. 
Но это еще не всё. Большинство квартир в 60-е и позже были разделены на две (входа-то два, а буржуев надо уплотнять!). На номерах появились еще и буквы. 
Короче, для случайного человека - желтый дом в чистом виде. А он и был желтым. )))

Поэтому разделение терминов на подъезды и парадные имело помимо прочего еще и практическое значение ориентации на местности.

Вот только не помню точно, чем это всё закончилось. "Парадное" как-то постепенно исчезло из активного употребления, а что взамен... "Большой вход", что ли... Но в принципе "парадное" понимали и понимают до сих пор как подъезд с "лицевой" стороны дома. Хотя фактически основной стала сторона задняя. Но это уже другая история.

Answer (score 1):

**ПАРАДНОЕ**,  ср.; (разг.) ПАРАДНАЯ,  ж. **Главный вход**. В доме п. закрывается на кодовый замок. Грязная, чистая п-ая.

**ПОДЪЕЗД,**  2. **Крытый вход в здание**. Войти в п. Главный п. Служебный п.

1) Из форума: Парадная... когда наконец "петербуржцы" избавятся от этого слова! ― И почему я должен избавляться от языка, на котором говорили мои прадеды? Если я с младенчества слышал, как называют парадную парадной, почему я в угоду Вам должен перестраиваться?

2) [О выступлении Артемия Лебедева на тему зоны личного комфорта | svetulok.livejournal.com](http://svetulok.livejournal.com/4343.html)

Мы говорим "подъезд" и это значит, что это крайняя точка, куда люди могут подъехать на машине (т.е. стоп, приехали - дальше придется идти пешком). А что значит "парадная"? Это парадная дверь моего дома. Сначала ты проходишь через парадную дверь и попадаешь в мой дом, а только затем проходишь в мою квартиру. Согласитесь, совсем другой смысл? Само название обязывает содержать парадную в чистоте и порядке, заботиться о ее красоте. Вдумайтесь: если ваша парадная загажена бомжами, то что же будет в квартире? Страшно подумать, вот и приходится соответствовать.Так может, нам всем в России попробовать называть подъезд "парадной"?

3) Это не подъезд, это парадная. [Это не подъезд, это парадная | supersasha.ru](http://supersasha.ru/posts/4076)

Comment: *Это не подъезд, это парадная.* - это личное мнение автора. Может и не стоит называть подъездами парадные входы, но уж точно это не "парадная". Парадная - (ж. р.!) это лестница прежде всего, а не холл. А то что питерцы имеют на то свое мнение, ну так это их право. Диалектное, областное, но не общелитературное.

Answer (score 1):

Вот почему в Питере парадные, а не подъезды!

[image: Вот почему в Питере парадные, а не подъезды!]

В каждой шутке только доля шутки. Как слова *бордюр* и *поребрик* используются для обозначения двух разных конструкций, одна из которых больше распространена в Санкт-Петербург, а другая — в Москве.

Точно также некоторые парадные входы в городе на Неве настолько изумительно прекрасны, что язык не повернётся назвать их *подъездом* ([адъективные ассоциации к слову подъезд: грязный, тёмный](https://wikivox.ru/word/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4)).

Comment: А Некрасов, типа, не знал? Когда писал "Размышления у парадного **подъезда**"?! Не знаю кому как, а по мне так свидетельство  Николая Алексеевича куда как весомее всех этих картинок с выставки.

Comment: @behemothus Стихотворение было написано более чем 150 лет назад и язык с тех пор успел трансформироваться (а речь ведь идёт об именовании бытовых вещей). Но аргумент у вас, бесспорно, весомый.

Comment: А куда ему трансформироваться-то? за последние 100 лет домов с **парадными** почти и не строили, **смысла** нового у термина я не чувствую. Речь о том, что изначально парадное восходит именно к подъезду, и только потом в живой речи у петербуржцев  стали проявляться какие-то признаки самостоятельного использования. Но терминологии-то не добавило. В Москве тоже есть подобные красоты. Петровский дворец возьмите. Там парадные или подъезды?  Вы поймите, я с большим уважением отношусь к питерской культуре, вопрос именно в термине.

Comment: @behemothus Соглашусь с вами.

Comment: OK. И да, а чем поребрик-то от бордюра отличается?

Comment: @behemothus на сленге дорожников бордюр укладывается на одном уровне с тротуаром, а поребрик выступает над ним. Правда будучи сам  из "поребриковой" зоны, ни от кого кроме непосредственно дорожников такого разграничения не встречал.

Comment: Ну про дорожников я тоже слышал. Хотя там как-то по другому было. Во. https://www.adme.ru/svoboda-kultura/chem-bordyur-otlichaetsya-ot-porebrika-962660/ Не буду спорить. Впрочем, мне хотелось это услышать от автора, может у него есть основания говорить о различиях не только на профессиональном, но и на бытовом уровне.

Answer (score 1):

"Парадная" чисто петербуржское слово и за его пределами практически не употребляется. Я сам из Вологды, где произношение ближе к питерскому, здесь говорят "кура", "поребрик", "греча", но "парадных" вы здесь не услышите.